# Nested context doesn't appear to return the inner context

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component  which provides a TransactionContext to identify the JSON data for that particular row.  Each column in the row consumes this transaction to fetch individual values.  This row also has a child  component that can be expanded/collapsed to reveal more details of that particular row.  This sub-component provides its own TransactionContext nested within and related to the parent context of the row.

When I break on the line let tx = useContext(TransactionContext) on a field in the accordion, tx is the parent transaction of the row and not the child transaction of the accordion.

The component hierarchy reads:

```
<TableRow>
   <Context.Provider key="row_1">
      <FieldElement key="id"/>
      <FieldElement key="effectiveDate"/>
      <FieldElement key="endDate"/>
      <FieldElement key="status"/>
      ...
      <Accordion>
         <Context.Provider key="accordion_1">
            <FieldElement key="description"/>
            ...
         </Context.Provider/>
      </Accordion>
   </Context.Provider>
</TableRow>
```

I'm expecting FieldElement 'description' to use the transaction context provided by 'accordion_1' but it receives the transaction context provided by 'row_1' instead.

So my question is are nested contexts allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is are nested contexts allowed?

[Yes of course](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts). Make sure to remember this rule as per [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

> consume the **nearest** current value of that Context type using `this.context`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the nested context works as expected.  I created an example here which proves it.  https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-usecontext-example-v8bos

I an still unsure why it was not working within my project code.  I suspect something regarding closure scoping.  I have since rewritten the logic so as to not use nested contexts.

Comment: What is the difference between the previously accepted answer to this one based on the original question: *"are nested contexts allowed?"*?

Comment: There is no difference.  I needed to prove it to myself by creating the sandbox example.  Thought I'd share the results.